# Create single boxplot from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have 3 dataframes (All,Young, Old) and all of them have 2 columns named the same (Participant and Number_of_whole_fixations). Each participant has a unique ID. For instance, IDBY06, IDBO08, IDBY56...(BY=basic young , BO=basic old ). The dataframe "All" has all the participants together (IDBY and IDBO), young has only those with IDBY, old only those with IDBO.
I want to create a boxplot with all three dataframes. Thank you in advance. I tried seaborn but I am doing something wrong.

```
import seaborn as sns 
everything=pd.concat[All, Old, Young] 
ax = sns.boxplot(x="type of participant", y="number of fixations", data=everything)
```

Comment: Three questions: 1. From your description, it sounds like the data in `All` is the combination of the data in `Old` and `Young`, is that right? In which case why would you want duplicates of all your data? It would be the same as doing a boxplot of `All`. Am I missing something? And... 2. Have you been able to make a boxplot of just one of them? And... 3. What is wrong with the current plot you're making?

Comment: I want a single boxplot to compare the data with all subjects and then by age (old and young) for easy visualization since I have limited space. The current code that I posted for the boxplot does not work. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add a category to uniquely separate young and old. You could achieve this by creating a new column based on `type of participant`:

```
df['Age'] = everything["type of participant"].str[2:4]
```

which should result in a new column containing either "BO" or "BY".

Afterwards, you can use this column in seaborn as a hue parameter two separate both boxplots:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(y="number of fixations", hue="Age", data=everything)
```